# In javascript, how do I make a class take an object's properties by reference?

Tags: javascript, object, oop, reference, pass-by-reference

I don't want to use the `extends` keyword because I am making a browser extension and I only have access to the instance, not class definition. so I am wondering if it is possible to assign the props of the instance to my class instance by reference. Below is a short example of what I mean.

https://jsfiddle.net/aL3n2fek/

I **don't** want to do `this.obj = obj`, since then I would have to do `c.obj.speed`

```js
const obj = {
    speed: 105
}

class Car {
    constructor(obj){
    Object.assign(this, obj)
  }
}

const c = new Car(obj);


console.log(c.speed) // logs out 105

obj.speed = 120

console.log(c.speed) // logs out 105 when I want it to log out 120
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [getter and a setter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

```js
const obj = {
    speed: 105
};

class Car 
{
  #obj
  constructor(obj)
  {
    this.#obj = obj;
  }
  
  get speed()
  {
    return this.#obj.speed;
  }
  
  set speed(value)
  {
    this.#obj.speed = value;
  }

}

const c = new Car(obj);


console.log(c.speed) // logs out 105

obj.speed = 120

console.log(c.speed)
```